Finding center of rotation on a plane using complex numbers
Let $V_1$ be the anti-clockwise rotation in the plane about origin with  $\theta$ angle  and $V_2$ be the anti-clockwise rotation in the plane about (2,0) by $\theta$ angle. finding its center of rotation of composition $V_2(V_1)$
around origin i have a transformation for $V_1$  that is $f_1(z)=e^{\iota\theta} z$ similarly for $V_2$ i have $f_2(z)=e^{\iota\theta} (z-2)+2$ then $f_2f_1(z)=e^{\iota\theta} ( f_1(z)-2)+2=e^{\iota\theta} (e^{\iota\theta}z-2)+2$. now how to find center from this without using matrices.

there is a mistake in your computations for $f_2\circ f_1$. also, what makes you think that the transformation $V_2\circ V_1$ will be a rotation?

i have edited it, it look likes transformation of $2\theta$,

look for example at the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$. does there distance remain $1$ after applying $V_2\circ V_1$?

if i know about center of rotation from there distance should preserve

Solve $f_2(f_1(z))=z$ for $z$.
